# Safari rending navbar logo sideways

Tags: html, css, safari

I building out a website for a client and for some reason Safari 14.0.2 running on Big Sur 11.1 is rending the logo in the navbar sideways (rotated 90 degrees clockwise). Even when I inspect it using the developer tools the source appears sideways. Everything renders fine in Firefox and on other devices.

Here is a live preview of the site: http://etc.lukesmedia.com

I have included the relevant css below.

Thanks for you help!

```
/* --- Global --- */
:root {
    --white: #ffffff;
    --black: #000000;
    --brown: #7d5a40;
    --dark-brown: #6c4d40;
    --dark-grey: #404040;
    --green: #4e9b4d;
    --light-green: #61b660;
    --grey: #8d8d8d;
    --light-grey: #cdcdcd;
    --stone-one: #9b9286;
    --super-light-grey: #fcfcfc;

    --main-font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    --max-width: 1440px;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width: 300px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    list-style: none;
}

body {
    font-family: var(--main-font, sans-serif);

    background-image: url("/static/assets/Background.png");
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: var(--main-font, sans-serif);
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

p + p {
    text-indent: 3rem;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: var(--max-width, 1440px);
}

.subtitle {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.break {
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
}

...

/* Main Navbar */
.navbar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;

    padding: 20px 0px;
    height: 80px;

    background-color: var(--super-light-grey, white);
}

.navbar .content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: var(--main-font, sans-serif);
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .content img {
    height: 100%;
}

...

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .navbar .content {
        text-align: unset;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        -webkit-box-pack: left;
        -webkit-justify-content: left;
        -moz-box-pack: left;
        -ms-flex-pack: left;
        justify-content: left;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    .subtitle {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, the source of the problem is actually the photo itself. There was some misleading EXIF orientation data encoded into the PNG file that can easily be removed. I uploaded a copy of the logo with the orientation data removed to Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOuqF.jpg.

Comment: Thank you so much!